# How can I improve my abstract iterable construct to remove need for explicit template use?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, traits

I want to have an abstract iterable construct of some kind that would allow my functions to accept any collection that satisfies specific traits. Basically, the idea is you have a method that looks like this:

```
void MyMethod(Iterable<int> values);
```

This should accept `std::vector<int>`, `int[]`, `QList<int>` and wherever else, assuming the traits for those types are implemented. The traits look like this, and what follows is my solution to this problem:

```
#pragma once

namespace RawHttp
{


/*!
 *  Template for generic traits of objects that can be iterated over.
 *  
 *
 *      @tparam TValue type of the value that is being iterated over
 *      @tparam TIterable type of the iterable collection/object
 */
template <typename TValue, class TIterable>
struct IterableTraits
{
  //! By default, iterator is size_t
  using Iterator = size_t;

  //! Creates iterator for given collection
  static Iterator CreateIterator(const TIterable& collection) { return Iterator(); }
  //! Provides const ref to item described by current iterator within given collection
  static const TValue& GetCurrentConst(const TIterable& collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return collection[iterator]; }
  //! Returns modifiable reference to item described by given iterator and collection
  static TValue& GetCurrent(TIterable& collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return collection[iterator]; }
  //! Returns true if the iterator no longer points at valid data in collection
  static bool IsEnd(const TIterable& collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return true; }
  //! Advances the iterator one step further
  static void AdvanceIterator(Iterator& iterator) {}
};

/*!
 *  Abstract iterable construct that can be iterated over.
 * 
 * @tparam TValue Value type for iteration
 */
template <typename TValue>
class Iterable
{
public:
  virtual bool End() const = 0;
  virtual void Next() = 0;
  virtual const TValue& GetValue() const = 0;
};

/*!
 *  Implementation of iteration over various containers using iterable traits template specializations.
 *
 *      @tparam TIterable 
 *      @tparam TValue    
 */
template <class TIterable, typename TValue>
class IterableImpl : public Iterable<TValue>
{
public:
  //! Shortcut for referrint to specific traits related to the collection type
  using Traits = IterableTraits<TValue, TIterable>;

  //! Captures the REFERENCE to given collection. The referred objects therefore must not be deleted while this object is in use
  IterableImpl(const TIterable& src) : _iterable(src), _iterator(Traits::CreateIterator(src)) {}

  //! If returns true, call to GetValue and Next is undefined behavior
  bool End() const { return Traits::IsEnd(_iterable, _iterator); }
  //! Advances to the next item
  void Next() { Traits::AdvanceIterator(_iterator); }
  //! Provides current item. UD if End() is true
  const TValue& GetValue() const { return Traits::GetCurrentConst(_iterable, _iterator); }

private:
  //! Container of the iterable data
  const TIterable& _iterable;
  //! Iterator over the container, defined for each supported collection type
  typename Traits::Iterator _iterator;
};

}
```

I have tested it and it *sort of* works, but I am not very happy with it. Here's an example on using this with `std::vector<TValue>` and `const char*`.

```
#include <Iterable.h>
using namespace RawHttp;

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

/*!
 *  Template specialization for std::vector
 *
 *      @tparam TValue Value of the vector
 *      @tparam std::vector<TValue> 
 */
template <typename TValue>
struct RawHttp::IterableTraits<TValue, std::vector<TValue>>
{
  using Iterator = size_t;

  static Iterator CreateIterator(const std::vector<TValue>& collection) { return 0; }
  static const TValue& GetCurrentConst(const std::vector<TValue>& collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return collection[iterator]; }
  static TValue& GetCurrent(std::vector<TValue>& collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return collection[iterator]; }
  static bool IsEnd(const std::vector<TValue>& collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return iterator >= collection.size(); }
  static void AdvanceIterator(Iterator& iterator) { ++iterator; }
};

/*!
 *  Template specialization that allows iterating over const char*
 *
 *      @tparam char  Value type of char* collection is char
 *      @tparam char* 
 */
template <>
struct RawHttp::IterableTraits<char, char*>
{
  using Iterator = size_t;

  static Iterator CreateIterator(const char* collection) { return 0; }
  static const char& GetCurrentConst(const char* collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return collection[iterator]; }
  static bool IsEnd(const char* collection, const Iterator& iterator) { return *(collection + iterator) == 0; }
  static void AdvanceIterator(Iterator& iterator) { ++iterator; }
};

/*!
 *  Prints each item in given abstract iterable container.
 *
 *      @tparam TValue 
 *
 *      @param [in,out] iterable 
 */
template <typename TValue>
void PrintAnyArrayAbstract(Iterable<TValue>& iterable)
{
  while (!iterable.End())
  {
    std::cout << "  " << iterable.GetValue() << "\r\n";
    iterable.Next();
  }
}
/*!
 *  Converts given collection to iterable construct and iterates over it.
 *
 *      @tparam TIterable 
 *      @tparam TValue    
 *
 *      @param [in] iterable IterableImpl has implicit ctor from the given Iterable type, so collections may be passed directly
 */
template <class TIterable, typename TValue>
void PrintAnyArray(IterableImpl<TIterable, TValue> iterable)
{
  PrintAnyArrayAbstract(iterable);
}

int main()
{
  const char* testStr = "StackOverflow";
  std::cout << "Chars of string:\r\n";
  PrintAnyArray<char*, char>(const_cast<char*>(testStr));
  std::cout << "  " << "\r\n";
  std::vector<int> numbers = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
  std::cout << "Numbers: \r\n";
  PrintAnyArray<std::vector<int>, int>(numbers);
}
```

The most annoying part is the required templated wrapper function that converts from the collection to my wrapper construct. Could you please help me fix the following things?

1. I would like to avoid the requirement for the special wrapper function that converts given collection to `IterableImpl<TIterable, TValue>` and than upcasts that to `Iterable<TValue>`.
2. I would prefer if trying to use the collection that doesn't have the `IterableTraits` struct implemented would cause a compile error.
3. I would also like to find a way to incorporate the concept of `const` into this, so that it can be used with both `const` and non-constant values.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You tag both c++11 and c++17. Any preferred standard?

Comment: Regarding #2, you provide a default implementation. That's in contradiction to wanting every use case to come from a specialization. So you can easily get an error by ditching the default implementation

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica If I remove the default implementation, there will not be any error as there's nothing wrong with an empty function call.

Comment: Not the function bodies. The whole class.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica JHBonarius asked a question about what do you mean by the dual tags of [tag:C++11] and [tag:C++17].  Had you actually answered that question, I might have posted a solution below, but I want the same information, and I may or may not feel like it when or if you provide that information in the future.  Please try to answer when someone asks a clear question in the comments in the future.  Thanks.  Anyhow, the technique you are trying to do is called "type erasure" in C++.  It is how the std function is implemented.  Look into that.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I forgot to answer the question. I have removed the C++11 tag as I have now locked myself in C++17 in other parts of the code, so limiting the solution to C++11 is pointless. Thanks for the hint on type erasure, I will take a look.